# Ember route map url with query parameters

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, ember-cli

this is my route configuration (route.js using ember-cli)

```
this.resource('xero-invoices', {path:'/loans/xero/:loan_id/invoices'})
```

but ember cuts query string when trying to route this address . How to fix problem?

Answer (score 0):

The portion of your route definition had a minor typo missing a closing curly brace, but I am assuming that is not really the issue. Here it is fixed for clarity.

```
this.resource('xero-invoices', {path:'/loans/xero/:loan_id/invoices'})
```

The resource above has a dynamic segment of `lone_id` not a query string. Query string support is currently in the beta builds of Ember and not in stable. Any query string functionality you are trying to use would be handled in your controller. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/

If you had a jsbin or more code I may be more helpful.

Here is a trivial jsbin showing the dynamic segment working - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/casana/1/edit

Edit:
In your example jsbin you are trying to use the `(query-parms)` helper for `link-to` which is only available if you are using the beta version of Ember. In your application controller if you remove it from your application template you won't get an error. In your route, since you are returning the query param as the model, the `oauth_token` is accessible via the `model` property in the controller.

Source: http://jsbin.com/bufukiqisika/8/edit

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('xero-invoices', { path:'/loans/xero/:loan_id/invoices' });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
   return ["red","blue","green"];
  }
});

App.XeroInvoicesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
     window.console.log(params);
   return params.queryParams["oauth_token"];
  }
});
```

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

  {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="xero-invoices">
  {{model}}
</script>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/bufukiqisika/8#/loans/xero/09870987/invoices?oauth_token=foo

Comment: thanks for answer. my code looks like this  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bufukiqisika/6/edit

Comment: but not working :x. I tried to add queryParams inside controller,but still not working. Should I update version or what I have to do?

Comment: To be clear, in this scenario you are trying to get the oauth_token from a url such as, `/loans/xero/LOAN_ID_123/invoices?oauth_token=foo`

Comment: but oauth_token is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use query-parameters which are defined on controllers.

Something like this should work:

```
MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['searchvalue'],
  searchvalue : null
})
```

And in you Template:

```
{{input type="text" valueBinding=controller.searchvalue}}
```

So your search value will be represented in the URL, e.g. “…/myapp/seach?searchvalue=foo”

See http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/